# Company-anaconda works with root level Python installation but stops working when switching to conda environment with conda.el

Tags: python, company-mode, anaconda-mode

I am on Arch Linux and use anaconda-mode with company-anaconda (here is a minimal [init.el](https://pastebin.com/UY4iiYbU) with which I can replicate the issue). I have Python installed both at root level from the primary package manager (pacman) and locally through Anaconda ~/anaconda3.

When I use no environment, company works well giving me suggestions. On the other hand, when I do `conda-env-activate` and switch to the base conda environment (or any other environment), company stops giving any suggestion. With `company-diag` I see "Completions: none(error fetching)". I still get suggestions when running IPython in inferior mode, but I see that company uses company-capf as a backend in that case, as opposed to company-anaconda.

I am a noob with both Emacs and Anaconda, and have been trying to fix this for a while. My first thought was that company-anaconda could have been relying on some Python package not available in the conda environment which I am not aware of, thus falling back to the root installation for that specific package and causing issues, but I have no idea if that is a realistic explanation.

Comment: Note that anaconda-mode has nothing to do with conda . anaconda mode uses pyenv to manage environments and not conda.

Comment: @mmmmmm yes. That is why I also use the conda.el package to deal with conda environments. The issue was apparently caused by incompatibilities between the jedi version used by anaconda-mode and the default versions used by anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a new conda environment and installing jedi-0.18.0, parso-0.8.2, and service_factory-0.1.6, which are the versions which appear as compatible with anaconda-mode, along with python-3.9.7. With this environment company works well. To see the versions I checked the file anaconda-mode.py located in the folder .emacs.d/elpa/anaconda-mode/.

Actually, anaconda-mode installs those packages itself in .emacs.d/anaconda-mode/0.1.14-py3/ so maybe the issue is caused by an incompatibility of those versions with the python version used by the default Anaconda installation.